# Quotients by simply connected closed subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, connectedness, topological-groups, homogeneous-spaces

I have come across an exercise asking for a proof of something that is definitely false: If $G$ is a Lie group, $H$ a connected closed subgroup and $G/H$ simply connected, then $G$ is itself simply connected. A counter example is $SO(3)/SO(2) \cong \mathbb{S}^2$.

However, I have been trying to figure out if this statement is actually true if $H$ is simply connected rather than just connected. I have tried to prove it by patching a homotopy from $G/H$ together and lifting it to $G$, but it does not quite work - I can not get the endpoints to match, even when using the simple connectedness of $H$.

I have not yet found any counter examples to this modified statement. I am not asking for a proof, but rather, is the statement true or false for $H$ simply connected?

Comment: This statement is true. It follows from the fact that $H\to G\to G/H$ is a fiber sequence and applying the Puppe exact sequence.

Comment: Possibly, the exercise should have been to prove that is $G$ is **simply connected** and $H$ is **connected** then $G/H$ is **simply connected**.